# getx navigation Error Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I need when the user click the button to add data to firebase, the snake bar pop up with a success message, then go back. But there is NO navigation occurs.

**the error is occurs when i use navigator is:**

> Error Null check operator used on a null value

**the code is:**

```
class AddProductController extends GetxController {
 
  addProduct() async {
    if ((addProductFormKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) &&
        pickedPhoto != null) {
      String docID = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').doc().id;
      var url = "";
      try {
        UploadTask uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref('users/products/$docID/')
            .putFile(pickedPhoto!);
        uploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
          url = await FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref('users/products/$docID/')
              .getDownloadURL();
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("products")
              .doc(docID)
              .set({
            "imgUrl": url,
          }, SetOptions(merge: true));
          Get.snackbar(
            "Sucess",
            "Your Product Is Added",
            snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          );
        }).catchError((onError) {
          print(onError);
        });

        return Get.toNamed(Routes.PRODUCTS); // => doees not work
      } catch (e) {
        print("\n Error $e \n");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you use this operator `(!)`.

you have to use using ternary operator example as :

```
void main() {
    Students? student;
    print(student?.name);
   }
```

Comment: if i am sure that a variable is never be null at this place, i can use it safely. if i remove the navigator line no error happens. the error occurs once i put the navigator with no navigation.

Comment: One example is this ```pickedPhoto!```?

Comment: yes, as i did it after checking    `if (pickedPhoto != null &&)`

Answer (score 0):

Implements Getx Service in AddProductController class.
it will look like this:

class AddProductController extends GetxController implements GetxService{...... }

Comment: why?
my code is work too.
why do you do so?